# What causes browsers to open "Save As" window when downloading dynamic content?

Tags: html, http, go, browser

I am experimenting with an idea to stream dynamic data from a web server into a file on the client device. To implement this idea, I am making use of the [HTTP Content-Disposition response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) and the [HTML download attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download). The following is my sample code, where the server is implemented in Go:

HTML:

```html
<a href="download" download>Download</a>
```

Server:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    // Handle download request.
    http.HandleFunc("/download", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"log.txt\"")
        w.Write([]byte("first message\n"))

        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        
        // The following for-loop takes about 30 seconds to run on my dev machine.
        for i := 0; i < 1000000; i++ {
            timestamp := time.Now().Unix()
            log(timestamp)
            w.Write([]byte(fmt.Sprintf("%v\n", timestamp)))
            time.Sleep(time.Microsecond)
        }

        log("done")
    })

    // Start HTTP server.
    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
        log(err)
    }
}

func log(v ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(v...)
}
```

This sample code works in that it successfully downloads all the content from the `download` handler when clicking on the "Download" link. However, I am observing the following behavior that I am unable to explain:

I have my browser configured to [always ask where to save the downloaded files](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95759?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). When running the sample code above, Chrome opens the *Save As* window only after the 10 second sleep but before the for-loop is complete and in turn the handler function has returned. Why did Chrome not present the *Save As* window when the "first message" was sent before the 10 second sleep? What is different between the "first message" and the messages being sent in the for-loop that causes the *Save As* window to only open when the for-loop starts?

Aside: If [FileSystemWritableFileStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemWritableFileStream#browser_compatibility) had greater cross-browser support, I'd use that to stream dynamic server data directly into a file on the client side.

Comment: You started to write the response. The browser is able to see that

Comment: But I started to write a response with `w.Write([]byte("first message\n"))` BEFORE the sleep...

Comment: Perhaps Go hasn’t actually sent any bytes. Do you have a flush function?

Comment: What happens if you use <-time.After(10 * time.Second) instead of time.Sleep?  Sleeping goroutine vs goroutine making progress,  Also, have you messed with the timing of the sleep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have Firefox open the *Save As* window immediately after "first message" is sent, Ricardo Souza's answer appears to be all that's needed. To have Chrome do the same, the response's `Content-Type` header also needs to be set to anything other than the default `text/plain` (thanks to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26342854/3634032)). Example:

```golang
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8")
```

Answer (score 1):

Go's `http.ResponseWriter` has a default 4KB buffer, defined at the [Transport](https://go.dev/src/net/http/transport.go) level:

```golang
type Transport struct {
    // ...

    // WriteBufferSize specifies the size of the write buffer used
    // when writing to the transport.
    // If zero, a default (currently 4KB) is used.
    WriteBufferSize int

    // ...
}
```

In some instances, when using standard responses, you can make use the `Flush` method by using type assertion with the `http.Flusher` interface to send the bytes right away:

```golang
if f, ok := w.(http.Flusher); ok { 
    f.Flush()
}
```